# React - Google only indexing main Page

Tags: seo, react-js

I have a react built app. And Google is only indexing the main page "/". I don't understand how React and SEO work together. Do you have any tips? Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried the Google Fetch and Render tool, and it only fetches the main page.

Link Example:

```
  goToPhoto(pageName) {
    const {history} = this.props;
    history.push(`/photo/${pageName}`);
  }

  <a onClick={() => this.props.goToPhoto(photo.pageName)}>`${photo.title}`}</a>
```

Comment: What happens if you type the URLs of other pages into your browser bar?

Comment: It goes to the expected page @StephenOstermiller

Comment: Consider testing it with javascript disabled. You might run into non-functional buttons. Also, its hard for me to give a solid answer because you're asking us to focus more on a specific framework and it might require specific code to perform the core HTML functions. As for google indexing, try to make quality pages that people want and make sure you **don't** use the robots noindex directive and make sure your server isn't blocking google from accessing pages.

Comment: "it only fetches the main page" - what about for URLs of your other pages? Or is that what you are saying; they don't return anything in the Google Fetch and Render tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old answer used to be use a product like Prerender.io in order to get Google to crawl it. Google has started processing Javascript and although a product that pre-renders a page for the engine makes life easier it's not the only answer.

A common problem I've encountered is that if your app takes too long to load, if your AJAX calls or event loops take more than 2-3 seconds, **Google will not wait**. It will go with what it's got, links included. The solution to this will depend very much on your architecture but I would suggest looking at speed, caching, CDN and other factors that could make it difficult for Google to load in under 5 seconds.